# Develop Native Application on Ubuntu with HTML/CSS GUI?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ubuntu

Redmond has a [good idea](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20067859-264/web-apps-get-the-ultimate-endorsement-windows-8/) occasionally:

> The next-gen Windows will come with a new programming foundation, letting developers build native apps with the same techniques they use for Web applications. Microsoft calls this new variety "tailored apps."

There is always a steep learning curve for developing GUIs; each new toolkit you learn is different enough that it takes a lot of time and effort and frustration. Thus developing in HTML with CSS begins to look very appealing: it's much easier and much more portable; and with HTML 5 and CSS 3, it is very powerful.

Is there any support yet on Ubuntu (or even better, a cross-platform toolkit) for developing native applications that use HTML/CSS for the GUI? To minimize overhead, I do not want to start a full browser session. (That's not very good desktop integration.) I am particularly interested in answers for native JavaScript or Python 3, but any language would be alright (easier to learn a new language than a new GUI toolkit, in my book).

**Edit**: I have found [this page](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/), but have not had time to read it all or test it. It linked to [Python XULRunner](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/no_wrap/tutorials/pyxulrunner/python_xulrunner_about.html), but again I have no previous knowledge of it.

Comment: inb4 "awesome interfaces" that break GUI style guides and confuse the end-user.

Comment: XUL? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Joy_of_XUL

Comment: @Diodeus: That's a really cute article title. Almost a misfit given the tone of the actual article.

Comment: Such a new idea from Microsoft, they had the same thing before with IE4 called HTAs (hypertext applications) which allowed embedding HTML in a small xml file with jscript or vbscript which could access Windows Scripting Host objects like the filesystem object and otherwise run with native permissions. Also, as mentioned, Mozilla XUL supports something similar, whcih can be run with XULrunner/apprunner or even with firefox using the -chrome parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This was asked on Ask Ubuntu back in August of 2011.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58996/developing-app-for-ubuntu-in-html-and-js)

In summary, the options are:

- [SeedKit](https://live.gnome.org/SeedKit)
- [The JavaScript bindings for GNOME.](https://live.gnome.org/Gjs)

There are more options, but those are the two "big ones".

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I was wondering whether to ask this question on Ask Ubuntu. Guess I should have looked around there first, tho this still seems like a legitimate question for StackOverflow as well.

Comment: @Kazark It's a legitimate question for either site. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write native apps in HTML/CSS and Javascript using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js, you can use node.js modules into your apps. it's available on Linux, Mac OSX and Windows

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add [QtWebKit](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebKit) to the list. It's like *SeedKit* with better support.

I'm using it personally on a project where we have native (C++) code for the data layer, business logic and the presentation layer is done via HTML5 and heavy use of JavaScript. As far as I know Qt can be used with python as well so perhaps you could use it for all the business logic.